# How to check site visiting after link clicking in bot created with Bots.Business

Tags: telegram-bot, bots.business

I have bot created in Bots.Business

My bot send link for web page to user.

User can:

- click on this link and go to web page
- click on this link and immediately close browser
- do not click link

How to check that user visit this web page?

Answer (score 0):

We have several ways:

1. **Place any secret info** in your web page. User must copy this secret and send to bot after web page visiting. Bot can check this secret. If secret is valid - user visit web page. Else not.

   It is more easy way for development but not for users.
2. Use [webhook lib](https://help.bots.business/libs/webhooks-lib#get-webhook-url)
   It is harder for development. Easy to users.

**Command /generate** - you need run this command as admin before

```
let webhookUrl = Libs.Webhooks.getUrlFor({
  // this command will be runned on webhook
  command: "/onWebhook",
  // this text will be passed to command
  content: "http://yourpage.com",
  // execute for this (current) user
  user_id: user.id
})

Bot.sendMessage(webhookUrl);
```

You will be have webhookUrl. You can place this webhook url in 1px invisible iframe on your web page now:

```
<IFRAME width=1 height=1 src=http://webhookUrl scrolling=no frameborder=0></IFRAME>
```

Also you can make GET or POST request in your page to this webhook url

**For user:**

Command /getLink
let currentTaskUrl = "http://yourpage.com"
User.setProperty("currentTaskUrl", currentTaskUrl, "string")
Bot.sendMessage("Link: " + currentTaskUrl)

Command /onWebhook:

```
// it will be executed on webhook
let webPage = content;
let expectedPage = User.getProperty("currentTaskUrl")
if(webPage==expectedPage){
  // user just visit web page
  // your code here
  User.setProperty("currentTaskUrl", null, "string")
}else{
   // user visit another web page with this webhook
   // may be he make refresh prev page or etc

}
```